# how to set text to text view based on the selection of item in dialogfragment and value of text in main activity, is it possible?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview, android-dialogfragment

Here I am trying to set text to a textview in my activity.
The text is set to the text view based on the text of the text view in my activity and the selected item in the custom dialog fragment.

The dialog fragment consists of recycler view and a button.when item is selected from the fragment and text of textview of my activity, and with both cases settext to the textview. I tried different code but I not getting how to achieve it anyone give me solution for it. is there a way to get it.

by using value of text and selected item, adding my math and condition to it. settext to the textview. I am beginner to coding can any one help me please I'm trying from 5 days to achieve it. please help me thanks in advance

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="YOUR DAILY TARGET"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/res"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Select a glass"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="0"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/glasses"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="121dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Listen selectedListen;

    protected void setDataFromMyDialog(Listen listen) {
        this.selectedListen = listen;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

        if (isFirstRun) {
            //show start activity

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page.class));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }


        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);
        Intent r = getIntent();
        double res = r.getDoubleExtra("res", 0);
        textView.setText(+res + "L"); // with this text value 

        double ram = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString());

        TextView gls = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.glasses);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DiaFragment df = new DiaFragment();
                df.show(MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Frag");
            }
        });

    }
```

with the text of textview above and selected item in my dialog fragment by using both the values the set text of TextView glasses.is it possible to get like this

DiaFrag:

```
public class DiaFragment extends DialogFragment {

    ListAdapter listAdapter;

    public DiaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
        setCancelable(false);
        Button ok = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setDataFromMyDialog(listAdapter.getSelectedData());
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public static List<Listen> getData()
    {
        List<Listen> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] images = {R.drawable.bottle,R.drawable.lotion,R.drawable.soap,R.drawable.soda,R.drawable.sodaa};
        String[] texts = {"250ml","300ml","500ml","750ml","1ltr"};
        for (int i=0;i<texts.length && i<images.length;i++){
            Listen current = new Listen();
            current.img = images[i];
            current.text= texts[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which TextView do you want to modify whenever conditions in the dialog frag are fulfilled? "The text is set to the text view based on the text of the text view in my activity" -> Could you make it more clear?

Comment: The text of textview its id(R.id.res) and selecting item, by using these, I have to settext to the Textview gls.